# A basic question about writing ros c++ code file

Tags: ros, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What shold I do if I don't kown some ros code means? Is there something like msdn in visual studio?

For example:
I don't quite understand the code below means? what should I do?
ros::service::waitForService("build_cloud");

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51761/a-basic-question-about-writing-ros-c++-code-file./) by [saddddddd](https://answers.ros.org/users/3927/saddddddd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-01-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saddddddd](https://answers.ros.org/users/3927/saddddddd/) on 2013-01-10**:
Thanks, but sometimes when I use the search engine, these has no results which may due to bad internet or something else. Is it normal when you use the Ros's wiki search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most of the packages have the APIs available if you know what package it's in.  For example, waitForService is in [roscpp](http://ros.org/wiki/roscpp). You can get to the API from the "package links" box on the right of the page.  That will take you to the documentation where you can find a formal definition of [waitForService](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/roscpp/html/namespaceros_1_1service.html#aabe996581255345b3383e66eaaedef5a).

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[ROS's wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki) has a search engine that can be useful. I always use it when I don't know something.

For example, in your case, if you type "waitForService" in the search box, you will get pointers to related pages and likely you will get what [you want](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Services)

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2013-01-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4